# can we change rundeck logs location to /data directory?

Tags: rundeck

We are using rundeck 2.8.4.1 we have number of rundeck job which will generate huge number of log files in /var/lib/rundeck /logs

we have housekeeping and backup jobs in place to purge the older logs in Filesystem and DB.

But my concern is can we change this /var/lib/rundeck/logs location in rundeck framework.properties file to /data directory ?which we have more file-system space than /var.

```
framework.logs.dir=/var/lib/rundeck/logs
```

To

```
framework.logs.dir=/data/rundeck/logs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, just modify the line `framework.logs.dir=/var/lib/rundeck/logs` by `framework.logs.dir=/your/new/path` (tested on 2.8.4 and 3.2.6). [Here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/config-file-reference.html#framework-properties) you have more information about that.

So, remember that it's for execution logs, not for "[system](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/logs.html#logs)" Rundeck logs.